# Yii2: Uncaught Reference Error

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

i have this weird problem. in my yii2 update.

i didn't change any lines on update function. i can update the record but when i submit the form it stays on where it is. but when i back to index the record successfully updated.

here is the screenshot from google chrome developer tool:
[image]

here is the screenshot of js developer tool being said:
[image]

i don't have enough knowledge regarding with jquery.

thank you for your advice.

Comment: its console not cosole... there might be some typo in your js file. please post the update function code

Comment: hi thank you for your response. i am new with this framework. what should i do to trace that problem? thank you.

Comment: are you submitting the form using javascript..? if so, pls share the js code. You can click that arrow in chrome developer tool, and it will show you the line that contains error (cosole).

Comment: i'd edit my question. thank you for your time for helping me :)

Comment: it got me stuck because the other form can perform edit very well. but this one can't perform correctly. although it can update but it stays on update page.

Comment: i figured out my problem. thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Hello its not yii problem but it is jquery conflict problem and load jquery file problem

Comment: hi thank you for your reply. how can i trace that my jquery load correctly.